# How to open NSSavePanel in FIFinderSync

Tags: swift

I'm make a Finder extension which can create file at selected folder.I have already set the "Permission/Access" of "User Selected File" to "Read/Write". But the panel doesn't display.

[image]

```
    override func menu(for menuKind: FIMenuKind) -> NSMenu {
        // Produce a menu for the extension.
        let menu = NSMenu(title: "")
        menu.addItem(withTitle: "Example Menu Item", action: #selector(sampleAction(_:)), keyEquivalent: "")
        return menu
    }
    
    @IBAction func sampleAction(_ sender: AnyObject?) {
        let savePanel = NSSavePanel()
        savePanel.canCreateDirectories = true
        savePanel.showsTagField = false
        savePanel.nameFieldStringValue = "newfile.txt"
        savePanel.level = NSWindow.Level(rawValue: Int(CGWindowLevelForKey(.modalPanelWindow)))
        savePanel.begin { (result) in
            if result.rawValue == NSApplication.ModalResponse.OK.rawValue {
                //write file
            }
        }
    }
```

And I set `FIFinderSyncController.default().directoryURLs = [URL(fileURLWithPath: "/")]`

I found some Finder extension App like 'Easy New File' can open save panel. How they achieve it?

Comment: if (savePanel.runModel().rawValue == NSApplication.ModalResponse.OK.rawValue) {}

Comment: @ElTomato It doesn't work too.

Comment: What doesn't work?

Comment: @ElTomato `savePanel.runModel()` doesn't display the save file panel.

Comment: I don't know exactly how you have changed code.  If you change the code in the way I have suggested, then it's something else that causes the panel to not appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `NSApp.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)` and `DispatchQueue.main.async` .

```
        NSApp.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let savePanel = NSSavePanel()
            savePanel.directoryURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: target.path)
            savePanel.canCreateDirectories = true
            savePanel.showsTagField = false
            savePanel.nameFieldStringValue = "newfile".localized
            savePanel.level = NSWindow.Level(rawValue: Int(CGWindowLevelForKey(.modalPanelWindow)))
            if (savePanel.runModal() == NSApplication.ModalResponse.OK),let url = savePanel.url{
                //wirte file to url
            }
        }
```